# symfony2 twig form registration included from external template

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

Be patient is my first question and my english is also poor ;P

Btw... im using fos for my website and all work fine, actually my problem is that i have the "pages" template made with twig and it have, at the bottom, a call to action button that slideDown an hidden div where i want to put my registration form.
I setup the hidden div and try to put inside my include:

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
    {% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}   
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

obviously it dosn't work:

Variable "form" does not exist in kernel.root_dir/Resources/JuliusUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig at line 2

probably for some reasons related to routing or firewall or security?
anyone have a solutions, suggestions or ideas for that?

thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As error said, you need to define 'form' variable in your action, or you could try to render FOSUser registration action instead of this.

For example:

```
{% render(controller(FOSUserBundle:Registration:register")) %}
```

Comment: Thanks Kap, i've tried but i get still the same error :(

Comment: Could you provide your action?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use include then you have to pass the `form` variable to your included template. Optionally you can render that template also from its corresponding controller. 
So for the first case you have:

```
 {% include("FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig") with {'form':form} %}
```

Where form here is the variable you pass from your own controller. Your second choice would be to render the FOSUB template like so:

```
{% render(controller("FOSUserBundle:Registration:register")) %}
```

Comment: i've tried bot without success, in the first case i still get the not form variable error in kernel, with the second symfony said:
`code`"Method "_token" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in kernel.root_dir"`code`
i tried also to add before the render: `code`{{ form_widget(form._token) }}`code`
but i get again the form variable missing error

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the `$form->getView()` as a variable from your controller to your twig template? You should have something like `$this->renderView('Namespace:ViewFolder:viewfile.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->getview()));`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i found a good solution using Edge Side Includes (ESI) includes that give me also additional benefits in cache control:

```
<esi:include src="http://localhost:8004/login" />
```